# Configure blazor wasm and separate identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a solution named Messenger which contains 3 projects:

1. Messenger.IdentityServer
2. Messenger.Api
3. Messenger.BlazorWasmClient

This is my IdentityServer Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // configures IIS out-of-proc settings (see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14882)
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            // configures IIS in-proc settings
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityServerUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityServerUser>();

            // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
```

Config.cs:

```
public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),

                // let's include the role claim in the profile
                new ProfileWithRoleIdentityResource(),
                new IdentityResources.Email()
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
            new ApiResource[]
            {
                // the api requires the role claim
                new ApiResource("messenger.api", "Messenger API", new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Role })
            };

        // machine to machine client (from quickstart 1)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "messenger.blazorwasmclient",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5001" },
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "messenger.api" },
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/" },
                    Enabled = true
                }
            };
    }
```

In the BlazorWasmClient, I added an AddOidcAuthentication method to the Program.cs like this:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            builder.Services
                .AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
                    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
                })
                .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ArrayClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

appSettings.json:

```
{
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:5000/",
    "ClientId": "messenger.blazorwasmclient",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "messenger.api"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "/",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

But I don't understand why I have this error message every time I start my solution:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the redirect URI and the PostLogoutUri must be an abosolut URI, not relative. Uris must exactly match what you setup in the IndentityServer4 client :

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:5000/",
    "ClientId": "messenger.blazorwasmclient",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "messenger.api"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified Uris in appSettings exactly the same as you did, but nothing changed, i have always the error message.

Comment: @Terai I guess the settings file should be named appsettings.json and not appSettings.json

Comment: @Terai did you check it's downloaded in the browser network log ?

Comment: it was something very close to what you told me, my bad, i didn't notice that there is an appSettings.json under wwwroot, so i created mine under the project folder.
Now i switched configuration under the right file and it runs successfully